# Words are behind img element after breaking line

Tags: html, css

I got a main articles section in my website where i got an img, and the right side the description of the img. After the words reach the container end, if should break the line and start after the img again. But my words are being behind the image ! Here's a fiddle that can help you to understand: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbL7sef7/). How can i make the words break the line and start again after the img ? is it possible to do this in the same container like i'm doing ? I'm giving the size of the container like this:

```
div{
    margin-left:2.7vw;
    background:black;
    padding:10px;
    width:50vw;
    height:49vw;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

And the img/words like this:

```
div img{
    margin-left:-10vw;
    position:absolute;
    height:40vh;
    width:25vw;
}

div figcaption{
    color:white;
}
```

It can be all seem in the fiddle. Thanks for the help !
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the image 'absolutely'.
Use `float:left` on the image and remove the `position:absolute` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/pa8qq9Lh/

Comment: Ok this really resolved it ! But, i got a question, i need to put images one above another, what should i do if i can't use position absolut ?

Comment: Google "Z-index". Hope I helped you out in your struggle.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `float` attribute to your img.

Example: `float:left;`

AND: Remove absolute positioning.

```
div{
margin-left:2.7vw;
background:black;
padding:10px;
width:50vw;
height:49vw;
word-wrap:break-word;
   }

 div input{
display:none;
          }

div img{
margin-left:-10vw;
position:absolute; <--- REMOVE THIS RIGHT HERE
float:left;
height:40vh;
width:25vw;
          }

div figcaption{
color:white;
          }
```

Comment: I need the figcaption to be in the right side, and even with the float attribute it don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to float the image, but left instead of right, and remove the absolute positioning:

```
div img {
    margin-left:-10vw;
    /*position:absolute; <-- remove this */ 
    float:left; /* <-- add this */
    height:40vh;
    width:25vw;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbL7sef7/1/)